# Documentation for Cell Linux Specific Contents in /proc

Tags: linux, cell

I am looking for documentation on the the Linux /proc file system, with regard to platform specifics for the Cell Linux platform. Of particular interest is how to identify if a given /proc/pid entry represents a process or thread on an SPU, versus on a PPE.

The system does provide some documentation in

```
man proc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks at the moment like the /proc is pretty vanilla on Cell Linux. What is different is the presence of the SPU-FS in /spu, which exposes information about (and indeed, the contents of) processes executing on the SPU helper processors.

The source code for the spu-top and spu-ps tools ([spu-utils](http://www.bsc.es/plantillaH.php?cat_id=470)) is useful for this.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most detailed /proc guide I know of:

http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt

Anything more then that and I think you're probably going to have to look at the kernel source code. This [annotated Python code](http://www.corepy.org/wiki/index.php?title=CorePy_Cell/SPU) for Cell might be a helpful starting point.